# Combine two rows in table using one column data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table where I want to combine two separate rows into one row. This is a product catalog that is storing information on separate rows. Here is the sample data and the expected results.

Table name: `ProductCatalog`

```
Product_ID  | Action     | Date
-----------------------------------------
0001        | Added      | 12/11/1983
0001        | Removed    | 01/01/2003
0002        | Added      | 12/11/1983
```

Expected result:

```
Product_ID  | Added        | Removed
========================================
0001        | 12/11/1983   | 01/01/2003 
0002        | 12/11/1983   | null
```

I have tried joining on `Product_ID` to get `Added` and `Removed` dates to be side by side in a new table or view but I don't get the desire results. I am not using `MAX(column)` since I don't get the desire results or maybe I am grouping wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way is conditional aggregation:

```
select pc.product_id,
       max(case when pc.action = 'Added' then pc.[date] end) as Added,
       max(case when pc.action = 'Removed' then pc.[date] end) as Removed
from ProductCatalog pc
group by pc.product_id;
```

You can also do this using `pivot`.

Comment: That just a detail but isn't it a good practice to use the declared alias `pc` when referencing to the table's columns?

Answer (score 0):

First what you need to do is to get data into two separate columns, after than you can wrap that in sub-select and group by `Product_id`, because only one of the `AddedDate` or `RemovedDate` will have value we can use `MAX` function to display that data, producing only 1 row per `Product_ID`

```
SELECT Product_id
       ,MAX(AddedDate)
       ,MAX(RemovedDate)
    FROM (
           SELECT Product_ID
               ,CASE WHEN [ACTION] = 'Added' THEN [date]
                     ELSE NULL
                END AS AddedDate
               ,CASE WHEN [ACTION] = 'Removed' THEN [date]
                     ELSE NULL
                END AS RemovedDate
            FROM ProductCatalog
         ) a
    GROUP BY Product_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like (pseudo code)

```
Select a.ProductID, a.AddedDate, b.RemovedDate
  from table a, table b left outer join on a.ProductId = b.ProductID
 where a.tran = "Removed"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from
(select *from ProductCatalog)p
pivot(max(Date1) for  Action1 in ([Added],[Removed]))as pvt
```